# Php vs Nodejs откуда большая разница во времени ответа?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

Мой Node js сервер отвечает в среднем за 8:мс.За это время он успевает логировать запрос, валидировать JWT,  зайти в mongoDB вытащить данные и отдать их.

Тогда как сервер на laravel отвечает примерно за 352 мс, в среднем. При этом работа у Laravel почти такая же как и у nodejs. С той лишь разницей, что laravel заходит в MySQL(но на момент измерения, в mySQL не было данных, и запрос занимал 0, 0 мс)

Откуда такая разница?

PS. Я все измеряю на своей локальной машине.

Answer (score 0):

в Php на каждый запрос каждый раз происходит бутстрапинг, то есть каждый раз стартует новый процесс и инициализируется. а Nodejs запускается один раз и запускает свой вебсервер. 
тестируете на локалке - может быть еще xdebug включен - он тоже будет тормозить. 
в третьих на ссд диске рез-ты у php могут быть лучше (если еще не используется).

**!Нашел такой ответ.**

Comment: Т.е. вам в голову не приходило сначала поискать ответ, а не найдя задавать вопрос. Вы решили сразу задать вопрос. Мда

Comment: @ArchDemon То есть мне дали ответ на другой площадке, и я его переместил сюда. Мда

Comment: @ArchDemon И вы еще дали мне минус? Как же я люблю русское ЧСВ сообщество.

Comment: @ArchDemon я  вас понял, больше никогда не буду отвечать на свои вопросы сам.

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что это я? Я кидаю минус, если вопрос тупой. Ваш вопрос нормальный.

Comment: @ArchDemon извините, просто меня достало что ситуации с минуса никто не регулирует. И можно спокойно давать минусы, всему кому за хочешь.